# Unconvert zipline string

Tags: python, quantopian

Is there a way to unconvert a zipline object that was converted to a string
or to find the string object in Fundamentals.columns and return the value.

This is the original type class `zipline.pipeline.data.dataset.BoundColumn`

Since it is in a frozen set I had to convert to string in a list to get sometype of order

```
for x in Fundamentals.columns:
    l.append(str(x))

l.sort()

for x in l[:5]:
     print(x)    #how do I
```

Comment: @MikeScotty the original list is a frozen set with no sort attributes

Comment: @MikeScotty Can you explain how the 2 problems are similar ???

Comment: I was assuming that BoundColumn is an object with attributes. Since you're saying it's a frozen set and thus has no sortable attributes, the linked question and the answers don't apply. I will delete the previous comment.